# How to embed a picture in header?

Tags: html, image, header, embed, element

I have a problem. I can not embed the picture in the header, that is even to raise it at least somehow.

I tried both padding and Z, but none of this helped. Padding generally ignores. I can only move the picture back, no more.

How can it be promoted up? Straighten up my code if I did something wrong. Initially I want the picture to be in the top right corner.

Please write a correct code with `div style="text-align"...`

Comment: I think I remember HTML *head*. What `header` are you referring to? even if inclined to `Straighten up [Ecklo's] code`, how can anyone do so with no code presented?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty unsure what your problem is. Maybe 
`background-position: left/right/bottom/top/center` 
can help you.

For better help, I recommend you to put some code snippets inhere.